# Google spreadsheets: how to convert numbers from 1 row, 15 columns to 5 rows, 3 columns with one formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a long row with multiple numbers and I need to convert it to multiple rows with 3 numbers/columns in 1 row.

input:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 42 | 33 | 75 | 77 | 24 |

output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 42 | 33 |
| 75 | 77 | 24 |
| etc |  |  |

I tried use transpose function, but it's is more slowly than doing it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `WRAPROWS()` function.

```
=WRAPROWS(1:1,3,"")
```

[image]